# c# Log4net file name with date in every minute and roll once per program run

Tags: c#, log4net

If I run the project in Visual Studio the log4net creates more logfiles with another dates.

eg: PO_Log_2016.11.28_21.00.12.txt and PO_Log_2016.11.28_21.01.04.txt

I would like to create one dated text file in every execution.

```
<appender name="RollingLog" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file   value=""/>
    <countDirection value="-1"/>
    <appendToFile value="false" />
    <rollingStyle value="Date" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
    <maximumFileSize value="20MB" />
    <preserveLogFileNameExtension value="true" />
    <staticLogFileName value="false"/>
    <datePattern value="yyyy.MM.dd/'LogFiles'/'PO_Log_'yyyy.MM.dd_HH.mm.ss'.txt'"/>
    <encoding value="utf-8"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline%exception"/>
    </layout>
  </appender>
```

Comment: What is your expected file output? What filename would you like and how many files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configure log4net RollingFileAppender in code rolling once per application start](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11801899/configure-log4net-rollingfileappender-in-code-rolling-once-per-application-start)

Answer (score 0):

To get one log per run you should use `<rollingStyle value="Once" />`

From the [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.11/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender.RollingMode.html):

> Once: Roll files once per program execution